# Finding out the current Identity Provider in Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: c#, wif, claims-based-identity

I have a web site which allows multiple ways of authenticating a user (e.g. facebook, twitter, windows etc.) Each of this provides a different identity name when the user logs in. I need to find out who provided the identity (ClaimsIdentity) and accordingly select the unique id for the user to add application specific claims to the users claims set.
I created a table to associate all the entities with users primary profile table. This table contains name of the identity provider, unique id provided by the identity provider and unique user id from the profile table.

My question is how can I find the name of the identity provider when the user signs into my site using these logins? The problem is if the user has same email address used for both facebook and twitter, I am not able to find out that information in the incoming principal as used in the authentication manager's authenticate method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typically use the `Issuer` and `OriginalIssuer` properties in each claim that you get.

If you use `e-mail` as the unique identifier:

```
var u = this.User as IClaimsPrincipal;

var c = (u.Identity as IClaimsIdentity)
                             .Claims
                             .First( c => c.ClaimType == ClaimTypes.Email );

var issuer = c.Issuer;
var originalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer;
```

Comment: Thanks Eugenio. I had asked similar question in a comment elsewhere. This answers that as well.